# Bisector plane between two panes? C#

Tags: c#, 3d, geometry

I do not know how to approach this problem as I am using API that has Plane data structure that is basically origin point, x y and z vectors that define a plane.

If I have two planes, how can I find bisector plane?
Is there a mathematical description for such plane.

[image]

Geometrically I would approach this problem by calculating intersection line between planes and then no idea how to define a point for direction that plane.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Before I tried something like this, and this get what I want, but I am wondering if there is a solution without doing intersections:

```
    public static Plane BisectorPlane(Plane a, Plane b)
    {
        Rhino.Geometry.Intersect.Intersection.PlanePlane(a, b, out Line lnA);
        a.Translate(a.ZAxis);
        b.Translate(b.ZAxis);
        Rhino.Geometry.Intersect.Intersection.PlanePlane(a, b, out Line lnB);
        return new Plane( lnA.From,lnA.To,lnB.PointAt(0.5));
    }
```

I am wondering if it is possible to solve this is not geometrically (calculating intersections) but mathematically.

Comment: I would have thought the bisector between two planes is a _line_ because there would be an infinte number of planes?   e.g. a _book-end_

Comment: Geometrycally the method I used is this: 1) Intersect two planes and you get a line 2) move two planes by z axis and intersect again. 3) construct plane from first line and second line middle point. In this way I get correct plane I want. Maybe it is called not bisector. But is there other way to do this without intersection?

Answer (score 0):

You already have got line of intersection. Now choose any point **P** at this line to make base point.

Get direction vector for this line (**dL**)

Get sum of **unit** normals for given planes **S**. This is vector lying in bisector plane and perpendicular to intersection line

S = (a.normal + b.normal)

Now calculate [vector product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of **dL** and **S** to get normal

```
BisectorN = dL x S
```

And normalize it (make unit length dividing by its length) if needed

```
bN = BisectorN.Normalize
```

Base point **P** and normal **bN** define bisector plane.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your approach and it gives bisector plane. But the problem is that planes shifts as it is constructed from origin and normal, not from origin and two x and y axis:

```
        Point3d origin = lnA.PointAt(0.5);
        Vector3d S = a.Normal + b.Normal;
        Vector3d dL = Vector3d.Subtract((Vector3d)lnA.From, (Vector3d)lnA.To);
        Vector3d BisectorN = Vector3d.CrossProduct(dL,S);
        BisectorN.Unitize();

        return new Plane(origin, BisectorN);
```

[image]

Comment: What shift do you mean? Two pictures look similar.

Comment: Look at green and red axis - x and y axis

Comment: And these axes have directions different from expected?